# 1000 value is not getting converting to currency correctly in cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an issue, where 1000 value is not getting converted to currency correctly in cshtml.

In the cshtml page, the following expression:

```
@((itm.SelectedQty > 0) ? (itm.SelectedQty * itm.ItemAmount).ToString("{0:C}") : "")
```

..returns the correct value for other values less than 1000 but not for 1000.

Example 1000 * 1 = 1 which is wrong.

Please suggest some solution.

Comment: If `SelectedQty == 1000` and `ItemAmount == 1`, the result is 1000, not 1. Did you double-check the values while debugging? Side note: Use `.ToString("C")`;

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I tried with .ToString("C") already and checked the values while debugging. Values are correct.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Please suggest something else. Do we need to handle thousand values separately.

Comment: No, you don't. You need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because your problem isn't reproducable. What does `string s = (1000 > 0) ? (1000 * 1).ToString("C") : "";` evaluate to?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed it is other way. @((itm.SelectedQty > 0) ? (itm.SelectedQty * itm.ItemAmount).ToString("{0:C}") : "") with values changed to @((1> 0) ? (1 * 1000).ToString("{0:C}") : "") just for more clarity. So When item quantity which is 1 multiplied to 1000 gives the wrong result. I think when converting to current using ToString("C") causing an issue.

Comment: Your question is really not clear at all. And as I said before your problem _(if I understand it correctly)_ isn't reproducible. Here's an [online example](http://rextester.com/NEDI35523) using quantity = 1 and amount = 1000.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed You link showing the correct result and it is how it should be. I am attaching a screensot for your reference. It is an asp.net MVC where logic is in cshtml. How can i attach a screenshot?

Comment: Please do not add screenshots of your code. Instead, check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to know how you can create an MCVE.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Code you have shown working through the console application, giving the correct result. May be it is issue with the MVC cshtml issue. Code line which i am referring to is very simple, but don't know why not getting the desired output. What i get in page out is $1,000 * 1 = $1 and $250 * 1 = $250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var currency = string.Format("{0:C}", Convert.ToDecimal(myoneyString));
```

Or this:

```
var currency = string.Format("{0:#.00}", Convert.ToDecimal(myMoneyString));
```

UPDATE:

use it according to your code like this:

```
@((itm.SelectedQty > 0) ? string.Format("{0:C}", (itm.SelectedQty * itm.ItemAmount).ToString())
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it did not work. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @PCDev, could you show me what do you mean by: *not working*? The same problem described in the question?

Comment: I have to amend the following statement so that i should get the desired result. @((itm.SelectedQty > 0) ? (itm.SelectedQty * itm.ItemAmount).ToString("{0:C}") : ""). So  changed the .ToString format as per your suggestion.

Comment: @PCDev, please seee my update. Note: what is the type of: `itm.ItemAmount` and `itm.SelectedQty`?

Comment: Type of the ItemAmout is decimal and SelectedQty is integer. I tried your update, still it did not work.

Comment: I will give it a try tomorrow in Visual Studio.